# WSO2 Identity Server STS Session

Tags: session, wso2, single-sign-on, token, identity

I may me misunderstanding the process of STS, but how do I maintain an open session on WSO Identity Server acting as an STS such that I automatically get a token if I open another application without having to log in again?
Also how do I close the WSO2 IS session so that I am asked to log in again if I hit one of the linked resources? I understand that WSO2 IS does not do single Sign-out, but I'm trying to understand how to sign it out at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is STS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security or what? Please update your question to define all abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

STS is token issuing service. WSO2 Identity server issues SAML (SAML1/SAML2) based tokens. Say one you authenticate to STS service and get a SAML token.  This token has limited time period.  You can keep this token and use to access web services that is secured with SAML. (that requires a SAML token to authenticate users). STS also have revoking, validating and renewing services  where you can do above functions with issued tokens.

But STS basically not used to achieve Single sign on rather than identity delegation. However, if you received bearer type SAML token, it may can use to access different services that trusts the STS service.

If you are using SAML2 SSO functions of WSO2 Identity Server,  you can achieve single sign on with different web based applications. [This](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/04/30/open-source-saml2-sso-identity-provider/) would be helpful for configuring SAML2 SSO.  Also you can do single logout with Identity server where it has been explain [here](http://soasecurity.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/).